# Does google node api support deployment manager function calls?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

I am working on an app which would deploy resources in GCP using deployment manager. I am aware of the deployment manager gcloud cli option and the REST API's for deployment manager but Is there a node js client library which abstracts the req, res function calls ?

I am aware of the following [link](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) but it does not have any example on deployment manager.

I am also looking for a way to perform server to server authentication/authorization using Google Oauthv2.0

Comment: You can check this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59390444/19371698)

Comment: thanks @SiegfredV. this is what I was looking for but could not find.

For those looking for code example to create deployment using node and deployment manager api here is the [link](https://dzone.com/articles/deploying-your-stuff-with-google-cloud-deployment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googleapis/deploymentmanager) for GCP Deployment Manager. For code examples, you can refer to the [link](https://dzone.com/articles/deploying-your-stuff-with-google-cloud-deployment) mentioned above.